# How to access the webpack output when app hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: reactjs, digital-ocean, webpack-dev-server

I have installed webpack-dev-server on a Digital Ocean droplet. On starting the service, it says,

http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from

But when I access the IP address of the droplet with port 8080 in the browser, it shows connection refused error.

On running a node server, I am able to access it through the IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @netoguimaraes suggested, I could not get it running through port 8080. I restarted the webpack-dev-server using port 80 and it worked.

`webpack-dev-server --hot --inline  --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a server local from outside the droplet if it is running at port 8080. If you want to get it public, try to run the server at port 80, that is the default public port.

You can configure apache or other HTTP server if you want more features or configs.

Comment: Thanks. I used `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline  --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`. It worked.